# multiples llamadas a una cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, twilio

tango una funcion que envia sms, desde el cliente solo se llama 1 vez, pero el loop queda infinito y envia multiples mensajes.

desde la consola de firebase veo que la funcion se llama multiples veces.

```
sendSms Function execution started
sendSms Function execution took 60008 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
```

lo que trato de hacer es enviar 500 sms llamando solo una vez la funcion , pero este actual codigo envia la mitad y vuelve a repetirlos, por ende el usuario recibe mutiples copias del sms

```
export const sendSms = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {

        const numeroTw = data.numeroTw;
        const targets: TargetSms[] = data.targets;
        const rbd = data.rbd;
        const idMessage = data.idMessage;

        const messageRef = admin.firestore().collection(`/RBD/${rbd}/messages`).doc(idMessage);
        await messageRef.set({ serverResponse: true }, { merge: true });
        let countSeg = 0;
        for (const target of targets) {

            if (target.messagePayload) return target;
            const textMessage = {
                body: target.plainMsg,
                to: target.targetNumber,  // Text to this number
                from: numeroTw, // From a valid Twilio number
            };
            try {

                const payloadMessage = await client.messages.create(textMessage); 
                console.log(payloadMessage) ;                 
                target.messagePayload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new MessagePayload(payloadMessage)));
                countSeg = countSeg + parseInt(target.messagePayload.numSegments);
                await admin.firestore().collection(`/RBD/${rbd}/targets`).doc(target.id).set(target);
                await timeout(100);


            } catch (error) {
                    console.warn('ocurrio un error al enviar mensaje', error)
                    target.messageError =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error));
                    await admin.firestore().collection(`/RBD/${rbd}/targets`).doc(target.id).set(target);
                    await timeout(100);
            }



        };

        await messageRef.set({ totalSegments: countSeg }, { merge: true });
        await admin.firestore().doc(`/RBD/${rbd}`).set({ config: { "countSms": admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(countSeg) } }, { merge: true });


        return JSON.stringify({ suss: true, message: 'Mensajes enviados' })

    } catch (error) {
        return JSON.stringify({ suss: false, message: error })
    }
});
```

Comment: podrias escribir el codigo que usas para hacer que la funcion se llame?

Comment: si este es https://pastebin.com/Sea5yN6E

Comment: @GastónSaillén ese es el link del codigo donde llama